# Different Output while using and not using 'break' in switch case in c++

Tags: c++, switch-statement, stack

I was solving the a question at HackerRank -
Question Link - https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximum-element/problem

In one solution I used 'break' statement in switch-case, in another solution I didn't.
Solution was wrong when I didn't use break statement. What is the reason behind this ?
Input -

```
10
1 97
2
1 20
2
1 26
1 20
2
3
1 91
3
```

**With break Statement** -

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int noOfTestCases;
    cin>>noOfTestCases;
    vector <int> st;
    for(int x=0; x<noOfTestCases; x++){
        int query;
        cin>>query;
        switch (query) {
            case 1:
                int number;
                cin>>number;
                if(st.empty()){
                    st.push_back(number);
                }
                else if(number > st[st.size()-1]){
                    st.push_back(number);
                }
                else{
                    st.push_back(st[st.size()-1]);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if(!st.empty()){
                    st.pop_back();
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                cout<<st[st.size()-1]<<endl;
        }
    }
}

//Output - 
//26
//91
```

**Without break statement** -

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;

int main() {
    int noOfTestCases;
    cin>>noOfTestCases;
    vector <int> st;
    for(int x=0; x<noOfTestCases; x++){
        int query;
        cin>>query;
        switch (query) {
            case 1:
                int number;
                cin>>number;
                if(st.empty()){
                    st.push_back(number);
                }
                else if(number > st[st.size()-1]){
                    st.push_back(number);
                }
                else{
                    st.push_back(st[st.size()-1]);
                }
            case 2:
                if(!st.empty()){
                    st.pop_back();
                }
            case 3:
                cout<<st[st.size()-1]<<" "<<query<<endl;
        }
    }
}

//Output - 
//0
//0
//0
//0
//0
//0
//0
//0
//0
//0
```

Comment: What do you think `break` does?  It's in the code for a reason.

Comment: I think 'break' statement skips the program to check further cases. Suppose the value of expression is 1 then after executing case 1, break will skip case 2 and case 3. The thing I am not understanding is when I don't use break, after executing case 1, switch will see that the expression is not equal to case 2 and will move on to case 3. Again, since case 3 is not equal to expression, we will move further without executing code under case 3. But this is not happening.

Comment: @atulya Jha "switch will see that the expression is not equal to case 2 and will move on to case 3". Nope. It will execute case 2 also, and case 3 too, hence the issue

Comment: @AtulyaJha -- BTW, to refer to the last item in a vector, you don't need `st[st.size()-1]`.  Just use `st.back()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following code

```
switch (x) {
  case 1:
    std::cout << "one\n";
  case 2:
    std::cout << "two\n";
    break;
  case 3:
    std::cout << "three\n";
}
```

If `x` is 1 it will print both `one` and `two`. It will then exit the switch block due to the `break` statement. Note that `x` will *not* be compared with `2` after printing "one", it will directly fall-through to printing "two".

Answer (score 2):

So I had a misconception about switch case statement -

**What I thought -**
I thought that in switch case if the expression is equal to any case D, then further cases - E, F, G, will not be executed, irrespective of the break statement.

**Reality -** If an expression is equal to any case D, then further cases - E, F, G will also be executed if we don't use break statement.

Thanks [Jeffrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4474230/jeffrey) and [Paul Sanders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5743288/paul-sanders) to clarify this problem.